# Unable to Set Up Subdomains on Plesk Server with TransIP Purchased Domains

Tags: subdomain, nameserver, ns-record, plesk, transip

I have my own Plesk server where I want to set up multiple subdomains for different projects. However, I'm facing an issue where the subdomains I create on my Plesk server do not seem to work. Here are the steps I've taken so far:

- I purchased the domains from TransIP.
- I configured the NS (Name Server) records on TransIP to point to my
  Plesk server's IP address.

Despite completing these steps, whenever I try to access the subdomains, they don't seem to resolve properly. What could be causing this issue, and how can I set up my subdomains correctly?

Comment: If you ever enter an IP address in the NS record, you have a problem.

Comment: What should i enter in the ns records field instead?

Comment: A domain name that points to the nameserver you wish to use.

Comment: So if my domain name is domainname.com i must put domainname.com in there?
Plesk also says someting about glue records. must i create them first and if i must add them first?

Comment: No. But honestly, SF is a place for *professionals*. Grab a book, read the wikipedia article or ask at superuser.com. It's ***not*** the place for basic questions about DNS.

Comment: Okay thanks i am going to ask it add superuser.com and ask around in office\